# SQL - compare dates with different time zones

Tags: mysql, date, convert-tz

I have a field in my `MySQL` database containing a date with a timezone that has the following format: `1986-07-10T00:00:00.000+02:00` or `1986-07-10T00:00:00.000Z` (Z meaning zulu time, or `UTC`).

I am trying to compose a `WHERE` clause that checks if the difference between NOW (my timezone = `Europe/Brussels`) and the date field is more than e.g. 18 years. Is there any way I can accomplish this using only `SQL`?

I was reading about a function called `CONVERT_TZ()` but I'm not sure i'm going in the right direction.

Comment: what datatype is the mysql field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to convert the time to your timezone, you could do somthing like:

```
CONVERT_TZ(
   REPLACE(
      SUBSTRING(date, 1, 19), # '1986-07-10T00:00:00' .000+02:00
      'T',
      ' '
      ),
   IF(
      SUBSTRING(date, 24) = 'Z',
      '+00:00',
      SUBSTRING(date, 24) # 1986-07-10T00:00:00.000 '+02:00'
      ),
   'Europe/Brussels'
   )
```

**Note from mysql manual**
To use named time zones such as 'MET' or 'Europe/Moscow', the time zone tables must be properly set up. See [Section 10.6, “MySQL Server Time Zone Support”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/time-zone-support.html), for instructions

**Update** exemple
if the table contains:
SELECT * FROM so_peter;

```
+-------------------------------+
| tzdate                        |
+-------------------------------+
| 1986-07-10T00:00:00.000+02:00 |
| 1986-07-10T00:00:00.000Z      |
| 2012-07-18T00:00:00.000+07:00 |
+-------------------------------+
```

the result of this query is:

```
SELECT tzdate FROM so_peter 
WHERE CONVERT_TZ(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(tzdate, 1, 19), 'T', ' '), IF(SUBSTRING(tzdate, 24) = 'Z', '+00:00', SUBSTRING(tzdate, 24)), 'Europe/Brussels')
   > '1986-07-10 01:00:00';
+-------------------------------+
| tzdate                        |
+-------------------------------+
| 1986-07-10T00:00:00.000Z      |
| 2012-07-18T00:00:00.000+07:00 |
+-------------------------------+
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, but this doesn't seem to work. I get syntax errors. Also, how can I use this in a WHERE clause?

Comment: sorry, missed the `,` just before the if, adding an exemple soon, just need to try it out in the database first :-)